# Pop the last item in a JSON Array in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, arrays, mysql-json

I've got an array of dates in a field called `from`. It can look something like this.

```
['2016-05-01', '2016-05-03', '2016-05-04']
```

I want to *SELECT* the last item (here `2016-05-04`).

I've tried this:

```
SELECT `from`->"$[JSON_LENGTH(`from`) - 1]" FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 3;
```

but got that error:

```
ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 2.
```

I've tried using a variable like this :

```
SET @count = (SELECT JSON_LENGTH(`from`) - 1 FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 3);
SELECT `from`->"$[@count]" FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 3;
```

but got the exact same error. But if I do:

```
SELECT `from`->"$[2]" FROM `table` WHERE `idx` = 3;
```

It works fine.

Comment: I've tried `SELECT \`from\`->"$[-1]" FROM \`table\` WHERE \`idx\` = 3;` with the same error...

Answer (score 9):

you can use :

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`from`,CONCAT("$[",JSON_LENGTH(`from`)-1,"]"))      FROM `table`;
```

to get the last item in a json array.

Comment: do you know to keep all the elements except last one :)

Comment: @ice6 added an answer that solve the op question and your question in newer versions of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8 brings a very straight forward way to accomplish this:

```sql
select json_extract(json_array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), '$[last]');
```

which returns

```
5
```

---

Can also do cool ranges, like everything but the last one:

```sql
select json_extract(json_array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), '$[0 to last-1]');
```

which returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```