# Get element value in a mysql nested json data

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-json

What would be the right way of getting **Ajax**, i.e. the value for the last occurence for key *child1Dob1*, from a json field that has a data structure that looks like the below,

```
{
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "data": {
        "child1Dob1": "Andy"
      },
      "child1Dob1": "Bob"
    },
    "child1Dob1": "Rick"
  },
  "child1Dob1": "Ajax"
}
```

The below query was an attempt from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443307/pop-the-last-item-in-a-json-array-in-mysql-5-7) but i am getting a null value, so obviously i am missing something.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`containerValue`,CONCAT("$.data[",JSON_LENGTH(`containerValue` ->> '$.data')-1,"]")) from myTable where containerKey = 'theContainer';
```

Comment: *the last occurence for child1Dob1* What is "the last"? the object properties are not ordered (rather than array elements). The most inner? use recursive CTE..

Comment: correct, the most inner would be another way of describing it

Answer (score 1):

For `CREATE TABLE test (data JSON)`:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte AS (
  SELECT data, data -> '$.data' subdata
  FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT subdata, subdata -> '$.data' 
  FROM cte
  WHERE subdata IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT data ->> '$.child1Dob1'
FROM cte
WHERE subdata IS NULL;
```